# Powershell > output on specific path

Tags: powershell

i have make this script in powershell :

```
$msbuild = "$Env:APPDATA\USBSAVE\usb.exe"

$arguments = " all -w "

start-process $msbuild $arguments
```

The script works, but the output file (out.txt), appears on the desktop.

How i can to save the output file into $Env:APPDATA\USBSAVE\ ?

Comment: What output file? Does `usb.exe` create the file? Does simply changing directories help?

Comment: thanks, the usb.exe create the file yes

Answer (score 1):

Modify your start-process command to include the working directory:

`start-process $msbuild $arguments -WorkingDirectory "$Env:APPDATA\USBSAVE\"`

Comment: @DigRea Glad I could help!  Please mark it as the answer if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your console prompt is pointing to your desktop. A simple solution would be to change your directory before calling the process.

```
$msbuilddir = "$Env:APPDATA\USBSAVE"
Set-Location $msbuilddir
$msbuild = "$msbuilddir\usb.exe"

$arguments = "all -w"

start-process $msbuild $arguments
```

I would also consider that usb.exe would have switches to define the output. I would look it up but that is more commonly associated to a virus it seems than a utility.

Was also going to mention `-WorkingDirectory` as well from [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but [Tony Hinkle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30260934/3829407) beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you my friends, its perfect :)